# 1C-Bitrix CIBlockElement::GetByID

Tags: php, битрикс, cms

Нужно в файле bitrix/php_interface/init.php вывести значение свойства блока.
Есть инфоблок с id = 6, у него есть элемент PATRONYMİC, как мне вывести его значение ?
[image: INFOBLOCK]
[image: patronymic]
Вот что нарыл в мануале, но не понял как использовать

```
   if(!CModule::IncludeModule("iblock"))

    return; 

<?
$res = CIBlockElement::GetByID($_GET["PID"]);
if($ar_res = $res->GetNext())
  echo $ar_res['NAME'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

GetById получает свойства по id Элемента, здесь нужен
[GetList Bitrix](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockelement/getlist.php)

```html
<?
$arSelect = Array("ID", "IBLOCK_ID", "NAME", "DATE_ACTIVE_FROM","PROPERTY_18");//IBLOCK_ID и ID обязательно должны быть указаны
$arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID"=> 6, "ACTIVE_DATE"=>"Y", "ACTIVE"=>"Y");
$res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, Array("nPageSize"=>50), $arSelect);
while($ob = $res->GetNextElement()){ 
  $arFields = $ob->GetFields();  
  print_r($arFields);
  $arProps = $ob->GetProperties();
  print_r($arProps);
}
?>
```

в $arProps будет значение свойства